# Third argument to patch decorator, how does this work?

Tags: python, python-unittest, monkeypatching, python-mock

This is something I discovered and am quite please with but would to understand what is happening. The use case is I want to patch and object in a test using a decorator but I'm not really interested in the mock object.

My old way of doing it.

```
@patch.object(Foo, 'bar', return_value='fake value')
def test_something(self, unused_foo):
```

I discovered this works:

```
@patch.object(Foo, 'bar', Mock(return_value='fake value'))
def test_something(self):
```

But according to the doc there is no third argument to the patch.object decorator.

```
patch.object(target, attribute, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)
```

So what is going on here?

Comment: There is a third argument. It's `new`, the one after `attribute`. (The fact that it has a default value doesn't mean you have to specify it by keyword.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, but now why is it that I don't need to pass it into my test where as before I do.

Comment: If you're providing the mock object to the decorator, the decorator doesn't need to provide it to you. The docs mention that this happens.

Comment: What I usually do when I have patches that I don't need their mock object is add a last argument in the test signature of `*args`. Something like `def test_x(self, *args):`